# Ext.Create returning classes that are already instantiated

Tags: extjs4

I'm making use of the extjs class objects through `Ext.define (...` and `Ext.create (...`. When I have multiple instances of classes stored within another class I'm seeing some strange behavior: the classes are not unique and it looks like `Ext.create` is returning my previous instantiation.

Checkout the JSFiddle of my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelcdillon/yBQe7/). Make sure you view the console log in your browser to see the output and weirdness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting an array in `Ext.define`. That implies that you're setting into the object's prototype which is shared among all instances of a class. Therefore this is not an unexpected behaviour. Create the array within the constructor, like here:

```
Ext.define ('Sunglasses', {
    brand : '',

    constructor : function (args) {
        this.lenses = [];
        this.brand = args.brand;
    },
    addLenses : function (lenses) {
        this.lenses.push (lenses);
    }    
});
```